# Formatting of Time in Go

Tags: go

I have a go program like this,

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
s := strconv.Itoa64(time.Nanoseconds())
fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Here, in my system, the output is 19 digits nanoseconds. Now, I want to get the time  like digits after 7 to 12 of those nanoseconds. Can anybody help how can it be possible in Go ?

NB: I want digits from 7 to 12 because in my system, time differs between them means other digits are same, so for me not needed. **And formatting inside println is not required because I give example just to clarify my code. Actually, I will use formatted time for another purpose. I need it in s :=.**

Comment: This looks like a poorly phrased question. You should be counting digits from the right not from the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s := strconv.Itoa64(time.Nanoseconds())[6:12]
```

Answer (score 3):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    s := strconv.Itoa64(time.Nanoseconds() / 1e7 % 1e6)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

This algorithm isolates digits 8 through 13 counting from the right. For a 19 digit integer, this is equivalent to digits 7 through 12 counting from the left. For the 19 digit number 1323154238948677000, these are the digits 423894.

> [func Nanoseconds](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Nanoseconds)
>
> func Nanoseconds() int64
>
> Nanoseconds reports the number of nanoseconds since the Unix epoch,
>   January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

At some point in time, the count of nanoseconds will increase from 19 to 20 significant digits. Therefore, algorithms that slice significant digits from the left, for example [6:12], are in error.

Answer (score 1):

to extract digits from 7 to 12 is easy, string slice will do the trick:

```
s := strconv.Itoa64(time.Nanoseconds())
fmt.Println(s[6:12])
```

so you get it.